AWS Secret Cache Java
I am trying to get the secret cache in Java working for the AWS Secrets Manager. I cannot get a secret returned but I can from the CLI. I am getting the error: "Secret Key Not Found"
Here is my code:
public class AWSSecretsManager {
    SecretsManagerClient client;
    SecretCache cache;

    public AWSSecretsManager() {
        Region region = Region.US_WEST_1;
        initializeConnection(region);
    }

    public AWSSecretsManager(Region optionalRegion) {
       initializeConnection(optionalRegion);
    }

    private void initializeConnection(Region region) {
        // Create a Secrets Manager client
        client = SecretsManagerClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

        cache = new SecretCache(client);
    }

    public String getCachedValue(String secretKey) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            String result = "";
            if (cache.refreshNow(secretKey)) {
                result = cache.getSecretString(secretKey);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

}


How are you getting the authentication for this code - i.e., local profile, EC2 machine role, etc.?

@stdunbar I am using the local profile for authentication

It works from my AWS CLI just not in the code. Not sure what I need to do

@stdunbar authentication is exactly where I'm struggling at the moment. When I try to getSecretString() it fails with  Unable to load credentials from any of the providers in the chain (e.g. AwsCredentialsProviderChain).
But how do I set up the credentials? I want to pass a EC2 machine role but I'm not seeing a way to do that within the SecretCacheConfig class
